# 2 column layout, first column fixed width, 100% height, 2nd column 100% width and height

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I've managed to accomplish this with `display:table-cell` but I've run into a problem, implementing **masonry.js** into a `table-cell`, it just doesn't work.

So I have to do this with normal divs.

I need the left column to be `40px` wide, and a height that grows with the content. The main column needs to be `100%` width or dynamically take up the remaining space.

Rigth now I have this, which works structurally but not with **masonry.js**.
**CSS**

```
div#wrapper{
display:table; 
height:100%; 
width:100%;
}
div#sidebarWrapper{
display:table-cell; 
min-width:40px; 
height:100%; 
background-color:#444;
}
div#contentWrapper{
display:table-cell; 
height:100%; 
position:relative;
}
div#content{
border-left:1px solid #ddd; 
border-top:1px solid #ddd; 
overflow:hidden; 
padding-bottom:100px; 
margin-top:195px;
}
div.clear{clear:both;}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebarWrapper">
          </div> <!-- sidebar wrapper -->

          <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div id="content">
            </div><!-- content-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div><!-- wrapper wrapper -->
      </div><!-- site wrapper -->
```

Basically I need version of this which **works without tables**. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you need second column to be fluid so..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DsLm4/) (Made another demo, `overflow: hidden;` was not required on child element)

I guess you won't need any explanation here as everything is self explanatory, removed `overflow: hidden;` from the child element which was not required in your case.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_container">Hello</div>
     <div class="right_container">World this is just a random junk text</div>
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
   height: 100%;
}

.left_container {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: #f00;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.right_container {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 200px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

Note: This won't expand the left column if the right one exceeds the viewport `height`, in this case we generally use `display: table;` for a pure CSS solution but you already ruled that out on first place so you can opt for jQuery.. Or you can use `overflow-y: auto;` on the container which you think might exceed the viewport `height`.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var documentHeight = $(document).height();
        $('.left_container').css('height',documentHeight + 'px');
    }).resize();    
});
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/DsLm4/1/) (With content)

Edit: Mr.Alien had the right idea I just made a little tweak :)

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var containerHeight = $('.right_container').height();
        $('.left_container').css('height',containerHeight + 'px');
    }).resize();    
});
```

Comment: Wait... no way it was that simple, I've tried everything stupid repeating backgrounds, calc, flexbox etc and you're telling me it's just min-height? Give me a minute to test this out.

Comment: @UzumakiDev you will need to set the parent `height` to `100%` as well :)

Comment: @UzumakiDev Added jQuery for `height` issue http://jsfiddle.net/DsLm4/1/ ... if you go without jQuery, see what happens http://jsfiddle.net/DsLm4/2/

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, the height issue was the problem I encountered the first time, then switched to tables. The Jquery fix seems to be the best solution right now, thank you very much :)

Comment: Could you add the Jquery part to you answer and I'll tick it correct?

Comment: @UzumakiDev ya sure :)